# service neo4j-service start/stop script

Tags: neo4j

I have installed neo4j on the linux server and it is working fine. I want to create a service for neo4j to start and stop it.

```
DESC="Neo4J SERVICE" 
NAME=neo4j-service

do_start()
{
   echo "starting!";
   ./data/neo4j/bin/neo4j console
}
do_stop()
{
  echo "stopping!"
}
case "$1" in
 start)
  do_start
   ;;
 stop)
  do_stop
   ;;
esac
exit 0
```

I wanted to go step by step.. I am using Java 8. Right now this is just for starting up the service. If i run this script i get,

```
starting!
WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
Starting Neo4j Server console-mode...
which: no java in (/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin)
ERROR: Unable to find java. (Cannot execute )
* Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) 7 or OpenJDK(TM) to run Neo4j Server.
* Please see http://docs.neo4j.org/ for Neo4j Server installation instructions.
```

But when i give "./bin/neo4j console" in the putty, it works fine. 
This is the output of 'update-alternatives --display java',

```
java - status is manual.
link currently points to /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java - priority 16000
slave keytool: /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/keytool
slave orbd: /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/orbd
slave pack200: /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/pack200
slave rmid: /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/rmid
slave rmiregistry: /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/rmiregistry
slave servertool: /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/servertool
slave tnameserv: /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/tnameserv
slave unpack200: /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/unpack200
slave jre_exports: /usr/lib/jvm-exports/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64
slave jre: /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64
slave java.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/java-java-1.6.0-openjdk.1.gz
slave keytool.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/keytool-java-1.6.0-openjdk.1.gz
slave orbd.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/orbd-java-1.6.0-openjdk.1.gz
slave pack200.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/pack200-java-1.6.0-openjdk.1.gz
slave rmid.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/rmid-java-1.6.0-openjdk.1.gz
slave rmiregistry.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/rmiregistry-java-1.6.0-openjdk.1.gz
slave servertool.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/servertool-java-1.6.0-openjdk.1.gz
slave tnameserv.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/tnameserv-java-1.6.0-openjdk.1.gz
slave unpack200.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/unpack200-java-1.6.0-openjdk.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java - priority 170079
slave keytool: /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/keytool
slave orbd: /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/orbd
slave pack200: /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/pack200
slave rmid: /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/rmid
slave rmiregistry: /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/rmiregistry
slave servertool: /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/servertool
slave tnameserv: /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/tnameserv
slave unpack200: /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/unpack200
slave jre_exports: /usr/lib/jvm-exports/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64
slave jre: /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64
slave java.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/java-java-1.7.0-openjdk.1.gz
slave keytool.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/keytool-java-1.7.0-openjdk.1.gz
slave orbd.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/orbd-java-1.7.0-openjdk.1.gz
slave pack200.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/pack200-java-1.7.0-openjdk.1.gz
slave rmid.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/rmid-java-1.7.0-openjdk.1.gz
slave rmiregistry.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/rmiregistry-java-1.7.0-openjdk.1.gz
slave servertool.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/servertool-java-1.7.0-openjdk.1.gz
slave tnameserv.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/tnameserv-java-1.7.0-openjdk.1.gz
slave unpack200.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/unpack200-java-1.7.0-openjdk.1.gz
Current `best' version is /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java.
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Which neo4j version are you using?

Comment: Neo4j-2.3.3 enterprise edition

Comment: If you can, you should upgrade to neo4j 3.0. Can you please add the output of command `update-alternatives --display java`? Also, you don't have to start console in a script, you should better call `./data/neo4j/bin/neo4j start` and `./data/neo4j/bin/neo4j stop` in `do_stop()`.

Comment: I have added the output of **update-alternatives --display java**. `java -version` is `java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode`. I got the same error when i gave **./data/neo4j/bin/neo4j start**

Comment: Should i set the path of java in this script? If so, how can i set it?

Comment: indeed you can add `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin` at the beginning of the script.

Comment: yes!! it works after i had set path in both bashrc and bash_profile